# How to extract number and subtract in youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

```
cd /home/ahmed/Downloads;youtube-dl -o "Kurulus Osman S02E%(ext)s" -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]' --merge-output-format mkv --playlist-reverse --playlist-end 1 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCuVYHE7O2A0XGkdhaU_M4-IkEIq5hSOQ
```

So basically what I am looking to do is have a cron command run on a youtube playlist to download episodes and rename them when they come out, my problem is with the naming.

I am looking to name it as follows "Kurulus Osman S02E**" where ** is obviously the episode number.

So 2 problems here, I am looking to only get the number from the title as %(title) will give me the whole command, I am just looking to get the number.

Second problem would be that the numbers are numbered as whole series episode, not the current season. For example, if an episode is named "Kuruluş Osman 59. Bölüm" I am looking to first begin with a fixed string "Kurulus Osman S02E" then extract the number from the title which would be 59, subtract 27 because first season is 27, which would give me 32. The number 27 would be fixed obviously, the problem I am having is extracting only the number, and I am not sure how to subtract a number from it after getting the number.
Final result would be Kurulus Osman S02E32

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl can't do the naming thing about episode but i can recommend you [filebot](https://www.filebot.net)? you can automatically rename your shows-episodes and localize them.